# CSS height on background image

Tags: css

I am having a problem with the background image on this div

```
 #lt_sidebar {
 position: absolute;
color: #FFFFFF;
 float:left;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 margin: 0 0 0 0;   
 width: 330px;
 height: 1800px;    
     background-image: url("/media/sidebar1.jpg");
    background-position: top left;
z-index: 0;
}
```

The problem is the height. If I set height=auto, it disappears. Height set to 100% always clips at the bottom of the window, I have to scroll to get to any content. So  I set height to 1800px (the height of the image sidebar1.jpg) but that means I always have scrollbars, even when there's no content to scroll for. Any recommended fixes for this?

Comment: You should use an image instead of background image. What exactly are you trying to do? Coz this is the right behaviour for background image.

Comment: please include your markup

Comment: add `display:block; overflow: hidden;` and use `height: auto`